# Sequence with multiple intervals

Tags: r, vectorization, sequence

`seq` can only use a single value in the `by` parameter. Is there a way to vectorize `by`, i.e. to use multiple intervals?

Something like this:

```r
seq(1, 10, by = c(1, 2))
```

would return `c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10)`. Now, this is possible to do this with e.g. `seq(1, 10, by = 1)[c(T, T, F)]` because it's a simple case, but is there a way to make it generalizable to more complex sequences?

Some examples

```r
seq(1, 100, by = 1:5)
#[1] 1 2 4 7 11 16 17 19 22 26 31...

seq(8, -5, by = c(3, 8))
#[1] 8 5 -3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible Maël. I suppose it's easy enough to write one?

```r
seq2 <- function(from, to, by) {
  
  vals <- c(0, cumsum(rep(by, abs(ceiling((to - from) / sum(by))))))
  if(from > to) return((from - vals)[(from - vals) >= to])
  else (from + vals)[(from + vals) <= to]
}
```

Testing:

```r
seq2(1, 10, by = c(1, 2))
#> [1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 10

seq2(1, 100, by = 1:5)
#>  [1]  1  2  4  7 11 16 17 19 22 26 31 32 34 37 41 46 47 49 52 56 61 62 64 67 71
#> [26] 76 77 79 82 86 91 92 94 97

seq2(8, -5, by = c(3, 8))
#> [1]  8  5 -3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Easy enough for you, not for me ;) This function is going to be very helpful in the future

Answer (score 3):

this looks like a close base R solution?

```
ans <- Reduce(`+`, rep(1:5, 100), init = 1, accumulate = TRUE)
ans[1:(which.max(ans >= 100) - 1)]

[1]  1  2  4  7 11 16 17 19 22 26 31 32 34 37 41 46 47 49 52 56 61 62 64
[24] 67 71 76 77 79 82 86 91 92 94 97
```

you would have to inverse a part of it, if you want to calculate 'down'

```
ans <- Reduce(`+`, rep(c(-3, -8), 20), init = 8, accumulate = TRUE)
ans[1:(which.max(ans <= -5) - 1)]

[1]  8  5 -3
```

still, you would have tu 'guess' the number of repetitions needed (20 of 100 in the examples above) to create `ans`.