# seq() function with increasing increment steps

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I want to generate a vector with the values from 13 to 79. The distance between the elements should be the index of the value itself. So that the output would be `13, 14, 16, 19, 23, 28, 34, 41, 49, 58, 68, 79`
Can i accomplish this with the seq() function? Is there a way to increase the `by`  argument with each step?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74900303/sequence-with-different-intervals; you can do `seq2(13, 79, 1:11)` with the function defined in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `accumulate`:

```r
Reduce(`+`, 1:11, init = 13, accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 13 14 16 19 23 28 34 41 49 58 68 79

purrr::accumulate(1:11, .init = 13, `+`)
#[1] 13 14 16 19 23 28 34 41 49 58 68 79
```