# Sequence with varying step size defined by a vector

Tags: r, sequence

I need to create a sequence from 1 to let's say 100 (it doesn't matter), with alternating step size not following any particular distribution or rule. The exact step size can only be defined by a numerical vector:

```
vec <- c(1,1,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,4,1)
```

How do I end up with the following sequence out of the above vector?

```
seq <- c(1,2,3,5,6,9,10,11,12,13,17,18)
```

The parameter `by =` from the `seq` function does not accept a vector as input, so any ideas or suggestions on how to tackle this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that the 18 in `seq` is an error: `cumsum(vec)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cumsum`:

```r
cumsum(c(1, vec))
#[1]  1  2  3  5  6  9 10 11 12 13 17 18
```

---

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74900303/sequence-with-multiple-intervals) a year ago, and one very flexible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74900455/13460602) is:

```r
seq2 <- function(from, to, by) {
  
  vals <- c(0, cumsum(rep(by, abs(ceiling((to - from) / sum(by))))))
  if(from > to) return((from - vals)[(from - vals) >= to])
  else (from + vals)[(from + vals) <= to]
}

seq2(from = 1, to = sum(vec), by = vec)
#[1]  1  2  3  5  6  9 10 11 12 13 17
```